# Woocommerce update cart button not working

Tags: woocommerce

I recently updated to woocommerce 2.3.7 and now the update cart button on the cart page isn't updating the changes i've made to quantities of items.  I can still remove items but the update cart button isn't working?

How do i solve this?

Is this a common error as i haven't installed any new plugins and everything was working fine on the previous woocommerce version 2.0.6

Comment: 9 times out of 10 the problem is an outdated theme. Can you reproduce the problem while using Twenty Fourteen? Take a look at their [self-service guide](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-self-service-guide/)

Comment: I found the problem was due to `wp_verify_nonce` condition in `class-wc-form-handler.php`  `line 408` i temporarily removed the condition and now the cart updates.  I can't think of why this caused the error because both remove cart and proceed to checkout both use the same condition and they work fine.

Comment: Still could be related to the theme if the theme isn't providing the nonce input with the current name.

Answer (score 4):

In case the used theme is not adding the correct *nonce* to the form, I would recommend you to correct the theme (eg. by using a child theme) and adding the nonce by yourself.

I did it by updating `/woocommerce/cart/cart.php` in a child theme, adding the nonce expected by woocommerce form handler `<?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart' ); ?>`.

By using this solution, you keep the csrf protection (I definitely  would not recommend to deactivate it, especially for a web shop).

Comment: Mmm I do have the nonce_field but error keeps happening. Actually, the nonce was already there in my WooCommerce version. Any ideas @ErikTheoboldt?

Comment: @xarlymg89 Although it is late, It may help someone else. I too was facing the same problem on one of my project. For the update button's trigger to work it requires the `cart-item` class on the <tr> tag on the cart table.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old question but I just fixed this issue myself, and in my case I needed to add both these lines below the button HTML code.

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions' ); ?>
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart', 'woocommerce-cart-nonce' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work for you, but I managed to fix this issue by simply de activating the problematic theme, activating twentyseventeen. De activating twenty seventeen and then re activating the problem them and Wordpress woo commerce started to play nicely again :)